# Show sections based on a control in WordPress Customizer using JS API

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer, api

I am trying to make the Customizer panel for a Slider in WordPress.
I have Sections in a [Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEbQE.png). In the first section, I have a [checkbox and a number field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Es2Tn.png). 
I want to show the number of sections based on the number in the number field and it needs to change dynamically. For Example, If I have 3 in the number field, then only 3 Slider sections are visible.
Also, all the sections and the number field are toggled by the checkbox.
I have been looking into the JS API for customizer and the most I have been able to achieve is toggling the number field. The Sections don't seem to move anywhere. `activate()` and `deactivate()` but to no avail. The js file I have been writing the script in has been hooked to `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` -

```
function mytheme_customize_control_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mytheme_customizer_control', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/customizer-control.js', array( 'customize-preview' ), '20130509', true );
}

add_action('customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_customize_control_js');
```

JS API is preferred but the one with active_callback will also work since that too did not work for me.

Comment: it's not impossible to have dynamic sections but it would be a big amount of work to code that in JavaScript. a easier way could be to use a widget for each slider. and then you create a sidebar that can store any amount of sliders.

Comment: @mmm got it! Will try that for sure. Meanwhile, can you tell me that if such an arrangement will be possible using active_callback.